# Information on iOS app wrapping?

Tags: ios, aop

There is a process called app wrapping:

- IPA is disassembled (taken apart + sometimes executable part of is is really disassembled)
- Some new binary code, resources, segments are added
- IPA is assembled again

Quite often this process is used as compile time AOP (to add some aspect like security, audit etc to application).

Have you seen any guide + tools which are used for this?

Comment: Yeah. `unzip`, `objdump`, `gcc`, `zip`.

Comment: @H2CO3: I have a feeling (need to try it) that objdump results needs to be massaged to be able to build back functioning app. Have you seen any guide on this subject (I would rather read it then spend next several days figuring out some small format incompatibilities).

Comment: That's right, but I haven't done much of this stuff... I think you will always need some kind of manual fix-up.

Comment: Vote up the question since I want to ask the same question. @VictorRonin, did you ever get any resources on this?

Comment: @windfly2006: Not really. Just small pieces from different places. I was interested in this subject, but had to switch to other tasks. If you will find anything, I would appreciate if you can share it with me.

Comment: @VictorRonin, thanks for your reply. If I find anything, I will share with you definitely, so far internet searching hasn't resulted in any real useful information.

Comment: @windfly2006: btw. Can you send me an email ( I have it in my profile) to keep in touch off stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Here is good overview on app wrapping for iOS: http://pauldotcom.com/wiki/index.php/Episode226#Library_Injection

Comment: Link was broken - this should be the fixed link - https://wiki.securityweekly.com/Episode226